# How to do 'View in Browser' functionality in personalized outbound email ? Any ideas please share

Tags: outbound-email

Any ideas please share. It will be very helpful

Comment: Hi user672. Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange.  Your question is very vague and does not show what investigation you have done so far and what problems you have come up against.  I would suggest that you take a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages within the [Tridion Stack Exchange Help Centre](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help) to help improve your question and clarify exactly what problems you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course simply publish the page used for your mailing to your website, however, theres going to be a bunch of stuff in there that doesn't make sense to be on the web (the text version of the email), or doesn't work (the merge fields like `[*Name*]` etc.).

One approach could be to have a TBB which strips the inappropriate stuff like text version, and converts the personalization parts into JSP tags/.NET controls. You are of course going to have to write these personalization tags/controls yourself using the Audience Manager API, and if your mailing relies on target groups to personalize the content, you will need to replicate the target group definitions in your website.

In summary, its not simple, but not impossible... however I would think about having the web version non-personalized, as that will make things much much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_2F2FFD2C8DF149549FD9A12F4C763F0B) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) explains you can use DWT functions (like `GetLinkTrackingURL("tcm:uri" or 'URL', 'URLName')` to transform URLs to trackable links) in your modular email templates as well as how to [personalize emails with merge fields](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_GDGD657775B5C4E1AB6D8E852ADF6502D).

Will Price adds [additional useful Outbound Email functionality with this extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/outbound_email_templating.aspx).

"View in Browser" is basically a link to your page, either hard-coded or resolved with dynamic linking and a little help from Will's extension to get an absolute url.

I agree with Jonathan that it'll help to know where you're stuck.